# jQuery .load() CSS not applying in Safari 6 for Mac, works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, jquery

I have a strange problem.  I have a PHP controller that dynamically generates HTML that `jQuery.load()` calls on to update the main content area of a website without updating the headers or footers.

Everything is working fine in Firefox and Chrome for Mac OS but when I totally clear the cache and load the page in Safari 6 for Mac OS X the styles are only partially applied (they are the same for all of the items in this CSS class):

[image]

If I reload the page and navigate so jQuery fires another `.load()` this time it works fine, like this:

[image]

Other posts said to reload the CSS as a `.load()` callback but that doesn’t seem to be the problem here, is it?

Is this a bug? It’s working in 2 other browsers.

UPDATE:

Here is the jQuery powering the `.load()`

```
$("#main-content").on("click", "#residential a, #commercial a, #industrial a", function() {
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        link = link.slice(1);
        if (link == window.name) {
        }
        else {
            window.name = link;
            $("#main-content").fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).load('index.php?jQueryLoad=true&url=' + link, function() {
                    $("#carousel").show();
                    flexsliderload();
                });
                $(this).fadeIn(500);
            });
        }
        return false;
});
```

Comment: How is the css embedded?

Comment: In the static header: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />`

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Yeah could you post a live example too?

Comment: It’s too complicated to post on JSFiddle or whatever so take a look at the live site.   http://www.assuredelectric.co

Comment: Added my jQuery code in the original question as an edit.